# Find two numbers in string with Ruby using Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

Results 1 - 10 of 20

How would I find the number 10 and 20 of that sentence using regex in Ruby?

Something like:

```
first_number, second_number = compute_regex(my_string)...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
first, second = *source.scan(/\d+/)[-2,2]
```

**Explanation**

`\d+` matches any number

`scan` finds all matches of its regular expression argument in `source`

`[-2,2]` returns the last two numbers in an array: starts at index `-2` from end, returns next `2`

`*` splat operator unpacks these two matches into the variables `first` and `second` (**NOTE**: this operator is not necessary, you can remove this, and I like [the](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/01/16/the-splat-operator-in-ruby/) [concept](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/))

Comment: The splat isn't strictly necessary is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = "Results 1 - 10 of 20"
first_number, second_number = a.match(/\w+ (\d) \- (\d+) of (\d+)/)[2..3].map(&:to_i)
```

The `map` piece is necessary because the regexp `MatchData` objects returned are strings.